# search starting at a specific cell on X WS, copy cell and paste to specific cell on Y WS , find that value, move 6 cells right and copy cell

Tags: loops

'search starting at a specific cell  on X WS, copy cell and paste to specific cell on Y 'WS , find that value, move 6 cells right and copy cell, then go back to X WS, increment '1 row and repeat until value "4STOP" is reached.

'this is my manual macro:

```
Sub beer12dec23_1231()
'
' beer12dec23_1231 Macro
'

'
Windows("beer list macro (2).xlsm").Activate
Range("A6").Select
Cells.Find(What:="start", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

 'nextrow:

 

Range("A13").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Copy of HM_GUIDE macro (2).xlsm").Activate
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("B1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "99900694235"
Cells.Find(What:="99900694235", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Range("K1622").Select
Application.Left = 6.25
Application.Top = 297.25
Range("N1622").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("beer list macro (2).xlsm").Activate
Range("F45").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F45").Select
Windows("Copy of HM_GUIDE macro (2).xlsm").Activate
Range("P1622").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("beer list macro (2).xlsm").Activate
Range("D45").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste


Cells.Find(What:="STOP_4", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
Range("A8").Select
```

' loop nextrow:

' end loop

```
End Sub
```